# Getting the page URL where an AJAX call originated from

Tags: ajax, http, url

Many (probably the majority) of AJAX calls are done by a browser on a webpage and that webpage has a URL.  Is it possible for a webserver to that's receiving the AJAX request to determine the URL of the webpage where the AJAX call was made?  I assume there isn't a standard that requires this data in the headers, but perhaps some browsers include that info?  Obviously this doesn't apply if the AJAX call was made from a phone app or other application without a URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very generically (though unreliable), check incoming request headers for `Referer`. That should give you information about the source page.

Just keep in mind it can be spoofed, absent, etc. and shouldn't be considered bullet-proof (though it doesn't sound like you need it to be anyways).